# Can a form class of ModelForm change the attributes?

Tags: python, django, forms

I've read a few posts in StackOverflow about the `forms.Form` vs `forms.ModelForm`.

It seems that when there is already a table in database for the form, it is better to use `ModelForm` so that you don't have to declare all the attribute again as they already exist in the corresponding class in model.py

So my question is

1. How to exclude a series of attributes of the original class, is the following exclude expression okie?

   ```
   class CreatePositionForm(ModelForm):  
       class Meta:  
           model = job_position 
           exclude = ('create_date','post_date','is_valid',)
   ```
2. When using the ModelForm, does it mean that the original attributes are not supposed to be change and there would be no more code before the class Meta?(just like the above code)
3. anyone can tell me what it the benefits of having a form over simply HTML
   form tags except that it helps report errors in

   ```
   form.field_name.errors
   ```

   I am new learner of Django and bear with me if these questions look stupid and thank you very much for your clarification!

Comment: The [`ModelForm` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) covers 1. and 2. - besides they're both "try and see" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As django docs state:

> If you’re building a database-driven app, chances are you’ll have forms that map closely to Django models. For instance, you might have a BlogComment model, and you want to create a form that lets people submit comments. In this case, it would be redundant to define the field types in your form, because you’ve already defined the fields in your model.
>
> For this reason, Django provides a helper class that let you create a Form class from a Django model.

ModelForm's are useful when you need a form that is closely related to any of the defined models. The advantage that ModelForm gives over the `form.Form` class is that you don't need to write extra code. For example: say you have a model defined as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    profile_summary = models.TextField()
    # .. some more fields ..
```

Now let's create a form using 3 different methods and see which one of them is the easiest to implement.

**Simple HTML form**

For a plain HTML form you'll need to implement the form elements in the template and then validate the data yourself as follows.

```
<form id="profile-form">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input name="last_name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Profile Summary</label>
        <textarea name="profile_summary"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

and then in the view:

```
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        # Do this for all the fields and validate them 
        # manually
```

**Using forms.Form class**

Using the `django.forms.Form` class you can define the form as follows

```
from django import forms

class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.IntegerField()
    summary = forms.TextField()
    # Notice the code duplication here
    # we already have this defined in our models.
```

**Using ModelForm class**

```
from django import forms

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
```

So using `ModelForm` class you can simply create the form within 4-5 lines of code and also have django do validation and display form errors for you.

Now to answer your questions,

1. There are two ways you can exclude specific fields from a form class. you can either use `exclude` or define `fields`.

**Exclude**

```
from django import forms

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        exclude = ('phone',)
```

**Fields**

```
from django import forms

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile_summary')
```

1. I don't really understand what do you mean by `original attributes are not supposed to be changed` ???
2. Benefits of using ModelForm

   - Less Code / No Code Duplication
   - Form Validation
   - Form Errors
   - Quick
   - pretty code

Answer (score 2):

It seems like "validation" would be kind of a big answer to 3 - it's usually a major feature of web frameworks. As for not using HTML tags, there's the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): if you're already defining what the fields of a form are (for validation purposes), why would you have to duplicate that in your templates? Have a *single source of truth* about how your forms look like (in Django, the `Form` objects, or `ModelForm`s together with `Model`s), and derive what you can (the HTML) from that single source.

Answer (score 2):

1-Yes this is ok to use,

```
exclude = ['create_date','post_date','is_valid']
```

more about model form here- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

2- it is wrong that you can't change attribute of model form, 
You can over ride it by defining as same attribute inside class
you can do anything like normal form to override initial,choices etc
 exa -

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, DateField
class CreatePositionForm(ModelForm):
    created_date = DateField(label="when created")
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super( CreatePositionForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        self.fields['your_choice_field'].choices = choice_list 
    class Meta:  
        model = job_position 
        exclude = ['create_date','post_date','is_valid']
```

3- most valuable benefit is that it enable form-validation by itself, whether if you write own html you will have to write long line of code.
for exa - you have given a char field it will throw a error, and add error class to the field attribute on html that is a big plus.
aprt from these it reduces overhead of writing of html while developing to check functionlity.

Answer (score 1):

1. [`exclude` should be a list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)(Although you can use tuples too, just quoting documentation, see comment). You should change it to -

   ```
   exclude = ['create_date','post_date','is_valid']
   ```
2. Nothing like that. You can change anything you want. You can add custom widget, alter form field attributes, even add more form fields to it. `ModelForm` just makes your model and form more coupled so that validation is done right. If you use `Form` instead for the same fields the model have, you have to redefine the fields types all over again.
3. Using a `Form` makes it less headache for you to manage the field properties. If you change something in model, changes will reflect to form's HTML automatically. You don't have to manually change HTML every time. Also it helps you with automated validations.

Comment: There's nothing in that link that talks about using a list vs a tuple. The two are interchangeable for almost all uses.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know. And here is the line - `Set the exclude attribute of the ModelForm‘s inner Meta class to a list of fields to be excluded from the form`

Answer (score 1):

Both Form and ModelForm extend the same class:

```
class BaseModelForm(BaseForm)
class Form(BaseForm)
```

So:

1. it's ok to exclude like that, but the problem is when saving: You will have to handle the excluded fields in the code if they are required or do not have default values
2. you can add extra attributes to the ModelForm object:

   class CreatePositionForm(ModelForm):
       new_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
       class Meta:
           model = job_position 
           exclude = ('create_date','post_date','is_valid',)
   but then you have to include them in the field list(if you want to render them):

   ....
   class Meta:
       ....
       fields = [...,'new_field',...]

   and when saving, you need to take care of that field.
3. Forms have default validation based on the FormField and Widget types you use. ModelForms also have validation based on the model's fields, error reporting per field/per form, saving goes straight to the db. On top of this I find it easier to use modelforms when going for formsets (multiple forms per page).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelForm and change original attribute, but in most case Django do it well !

Django forms are very useful, you can perform advanced validation, add some business logic. Well, django Forms render HTML, but even if your Django project does not serve HTML, you are probably still using Django forms.

Your exclude code seems to be ok, but note that the use of `Meta.excludes` is considered a security risk. Use `Meta.fields`

Comment: What security risk, im curious! :)

Comment: Where we used Meta.fields we know exactly what fields each form is designed to handle. Changing the model doesn't alter what the form exposes, and we can sleep soundly knowing that Ice Cream Stores are more secure. Source: [Two Scoops of Django](https://django.2scoops.org) book

Comment: Yeah, and to elaborate on the words "security" it's basically a thing of saying what fields to use explicitly than implicitly as `Meta.exclude` does. Basically what it does is that if you add more fields to your model using `fields` is better than `exclude` since your form won't add the new field if you forgot to include it.